# Unable to validate the visibility of the notification message using explicit wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to validate whether a notification message appears on the screen upon successful save.
The Problem here is the notification message disappears in few seconds(less than 5 sec).

I tried the following code to validate whether notification message appears or not:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Notification Message')]")));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The Exception is ::::::::::::: "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Additionally I also tried the following

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Notification Message')]")));
```

In both the cases Exception is thrown though the notification message appears.

Please recommend if any other way to validate the notification message.

Comment: Please provide Html code for reference.

Comment: HTML Code disappears from the DOM as soon as the Notification disappears.

Comment: then how did you find xpath of notification message ?

Comment: @Harish That's really going to depend on the implementation of the _toast message_ - if it is using HTML5 notifications? Without more information, it's going to be really hard to provide assistance.

Comment: Regarding How I obtained xpath...It Appears on the DOM for a second I Noticed the Tag as h2 and text on the notification message

Comment: Please provide error message also, and html code (if not secure). html code you can try to get, in chrome, using debug.

Comment: Provide the relevant HTML for the toast message. Also, does the HTML exist in the DOM even if the toast is not visible? In your code you are waiting for present... which just means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it is visible. I would expect that you would want to wait for visible, validate the message, and then wait for invisible.

Comment: I checked for presence only after the Visibility check failed...if u could see the code above...HTML disappears from the DOM as soon as the toast message disappears